# Class inside a block - where would this ever make sense?

Tags: java, language-features

I ran over an interesting [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637229/java-language-specification-cannot-understand-blockstatement) yesterday.

The current definition for a `Block Statement` is [here](http://www.it.bton.ac.uk/staff/rnb/bosware/javaSyntax/rulesLinked.html#BlockStatement).

```
BlockStatement: LocalVariableDeclarationStatement ClassDeclaration Statement
```

This means that you can do something like this

```
class A {

    public void doIt() {
        class B {}
        B b = new B();
    }
}
```

or this

```
public class Test {
    static 
    {
        class C {}
        C c = new C();
    }
}
```

Good to know that this actually works, but can anybody think of a reasonable use case where you would actually want to do something like this? Where it probably would be the most elegant solution compared to something else?

Comment: As I answered in that other question, it can be used as an alternative to an anonymous inner class, if you need to define a constructor in the class (which isn't possible in an anonymous inner class).

Comment: That's definitely an advantage, but still I would want to prefer an inner class of the enclosing class for that, no?

Comment: Why? Making a local class out of it limits the scope, it's often a good idea to make the scope of variables and classes as small as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine you'd do this when extending or implementing a class or interface, where the implementation is very specific to the scope that you're in. Typically you see people doing this with [*anonymous inner classes*](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/anonymousclasses.html), but if you want to get a little more code reuse, while still restricting the class to the scope of the method you're in, you could use one of these *local inner classes* instead.

#### Update

In many cases, you're going to find that a private static class makes more sense than a local inner class. However, standard practice dictates that we restrict the scope of a class to the narrowest scope that works, to avoid cluttering namespaces and such.

Also, Java uses local classes to implement/imitate *closures*. Converting `CloseWindowListener` in the code below into a private static class would require a lot more code, because you'd have to create a custom constructor and private field to contain the `window` variable. But because the class is defined within the scope of this method, we can access it directly instead.

```
public void setupWindowHandlers(Window window) {
    class CloseWindowListener extends ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            window.close();
        }
    }
    closeButton.addActionListener( new CloseWindowListener() );
    cancelButton.addActionListener( new CloseWindowListener() );
}
```

Comment: I see, it's more code reuse than using anonymous inner classes (a lot of boilerplate if you do this multiple times in the same method) - but instead of scaring your co-workers with such a construct wouldn't it make more sense to use a private (static) inner class of the enclosing class :) ?

Comment: Nice argument. It beats using two anonymous inner classes because of the boilerplate that is saved.

Answer (score 2):

From Effective Java 2nd Edition:

> If you need to create instances from
>   only one location and there is no
>   preexisting type that characterizes
>   the class, then make it a local class.